# Navigate to previous input when pressed to delete angularjs Directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following directive to move to the next input after the field is filled in, for that I have the Following code on my directive:

```
 function moveNextInput() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element) {
                element.on("input", function (e) {
                    if (element.val().length == element.attr("maxlength")) {
                        var $nextElement = element.next();
                        if ($nextElement.length) {
                            $nextElement[0].focus();
                        } });
            }
        };
    }
```

I want to make the opposite of this happen, when pressed to delete/backspace, on mobile input, I want to navigate to the previous input.

My input is as the following illustration:

before filling: _  _  _

after filling (example):  1  2  3

how to make this happen? I am having trouble detecting that delete was pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my already existing directive to the following:

```
  function moveNextInput() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element) {
                element.on("input", function (e) {
                    if (element.val().length == element.attr("maxlength")) {
                        var $nextElement = element.next();
                        if ($nextElement.length) {
                            $nextElement[0].focus();
                        }
                    }
                }).keyup(function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 8 && !this.value) {
                        $(this).prev().focus();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

this works as well for me

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work

```
function deleteElementInput() {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function($scope, element) {
       element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
         if (event.which === 8 || event.which === 46) {
           if (element.val().length == 0) {
                var $prevElement = element.prev();
                if ($prevElement.length) {
                    $prevElement[0].focus();
                } 
           }
           event.preventDefault();
         }
       });
     }
   }
 };
```

Comment: I ended up adding this: 
 .keyup(function (e) {
                    if (e.which === 8 && !this.value) {
                        $(this).prev().focus();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
})();
and it also worked

Comment: Great , though using jquery is not a great choice but seems perfect if its reducing and satisfying the code :)

Comment: why is query not a good choice? I just want to understand that

Comment: Becase AngularJS digest cycle wont run if we do any angular DOM manipulation or scope variable manipulation using JQuery.